# Optimate ionic page load with firebase

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I develop an App with ionic and I'm using firebase for it. I have links to the firebase storage and I'm loading images from there. The images are about 200-500kb. I'm using a ng-repeat to loop trogh the text in firebase and loading the images from the firebase storage url. It is too slow for production. What options do I have to Speed up the page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has no customization options for [this use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991426/firebase-does-caching-improve-performance) to my knowledge. In my humble opinion, here are your options:

- Use a [profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime?hl=en) to ensure the delay is solely firebase and not something related to Ionic, Cordova, or Angular. Given the file sizes you mentioned, I think this is unlikely, but should there be an issue on the client-side your situation will be easier to pinpoint and fix
- Using placeholder layouts or dominant color lazy loading (like pinterest) as described [here](https://kyusuf.com/post/fake-it-til-you-make-it-css?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email) may satisfy usability for production
- Change the image format to something that uses higher compression — e.g. png to jpg
- Change the UI to show low-res image thumbnails at first and then allow the user to select the larger files
- Migrate to a different backend service

Comment: Thank you! Just for another app, what backend service do you recommend compared with Firebase?

Comment: Well facebook hosts its images on [Akamai](https://developer.akamai.com/api/imaging/imaging/overview.html) so that is the best and most expensive solution. For something free, I am a fan of [OpenShift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShift) because you get Amazon EC2 like servers without strings attached - you could create a simple image file server like [this](http://mifo.sk/post/file-sharing-on-openshift/).

Comment: Thanks! OpenShift looks really cool. I will have a look.  Hey do you now an answer to this issue? I'm stuck on this since 6 hours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766985/http-equiv-content-security-policy-works-in-browser-but-not-on-android-device